# CMake cyclic dependency of external and internal static library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I have a framework/code generator with a static library libA.a which contains symbols which are defined by the generated code (libB). So essentially, I imagine the dependency graph is circular, since the generated code uses API from libA:

```
libB -> libA -> libB
```

libB I am building, and then using to create an executable

```
set(LIBA libA.a)

add_library(libB "${libb_sources}")

target_link_libraries(libB libA) 

add_executable(execAB ${MAIN_SRC})
target_link_libraries(execAB libB)
```

The issue I have is that during linking, libA symbols defined in libB are not getting resolved. Relatively normal circular dependency, but including an external library not built during our build.

```
/usr/local/lib/libara_vsomeipbinding.a(vsomeip_proxy_factory.cc.o): In function `ara::com::internal::vsomeip::runtime::VSomeIPProxyFactoryImpl::AvailabilityHandler(unsigned short, unsigned short, bool)':
vsomeip_proxy_factory.cc:(.text+0x7ff): undefined reference to `ara::com::internal::vsomeip::runtime::VSomeIPServiceMapping::GetMappingForVSomeIPServiceId(unsigned short)'
```

What I have tried so far:

- making libB an OBJECT library resolves the issue, but I have the requirement to make it a static library, to keep in line with other parts of the project, so that is not a solution
- defining an intermediate static library libC, with libB being a OBJECT library -> does not help because the situation is essentially unchanged, I guess.
- having a intermediate library libC, and defining the dependencies multiple times to have them appear multiple times in the linker command line. Didn't work, they only appeared once.
- defining a circular dependency between libB and libC, in the hope that dependencies also get doubled. No, only those two appear twice on the command line.

Other issues:

- gcc-only solutions like `--start-group/--end-group` is also not an option because we target both Visual Studio and gcc
- I don't want to add libA as dependency of execAB if possible, the dependency should be encapsulated in some (static if possible) library target

**How do I get the linker to link libA and libB as group/ twice so all symbols get properly resolved?**

---

More detailed information:

I am building a framework on top of the ARA reference implementation of adaptive AUTOSAR. In AUTOSAR, services / service interfaces are defined in XML files, ARA has a code generator which reads these and generates code for these services / for their communication, which my framework uses. During my cmake build, the ARAgen generator runs to generate the code.

There is, of course, a static part of the ARA API, this is libA. In the generated portion of the code, which is part of libB, there is, for example, `ara::com::internal::vsomeip::runtime::VSomeIPServiceMapping::GetMappingForVSomeIPServiceId(unsigned short)`, which according to the name I would say maps numeric IDs to the specific (generated) Services. This is used by the static ARA part to map from service id to service object/class.

On the other hand, the static ARA library of course contains code that the generated part uses (base classes and such, I guess).

Comment: Circular dependencies between static libraries are allowed. CMake should automatically links against static libraries twice to resolve all symbols. If libA is external, add it via `add_library(libA IMPORTED STATIC....)`?

Comment: Can you provide the *specific* error you are receiving? "*not getting resolved*"... is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: @squareskittles Done - it is a link time error about undefined references.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried that just now - it sounds like it could potentially work, but does not because when I use `targer_link_libraries(libA libB)` to define the circular dependency, cmake complains that libA, as external target, has a non-existent path in `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` - that path is only generated during the build (of a dependency of) libB. Seems like a strange restriction, but ok.

Comment: Is `libB` built as a static or shared library? Your CMake doesn't indicate `STATIC` or `SHARED`, which means it would default to whatever `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is set to. You do not show this value, if you are setting it somewhere.

Comment: Why would you specify dependency on external library? You don't compile it. Cmake doesn't need to know how to compile imported library, it's... imported. External. Already build.

Comment: Any cyclic dependency between libraries or classes means they are not separable. This is clear indication of bad architecture. Usually this mean you should split part of functionality to third library or class and in this way break the cycle. You can try maintain cycle, but as a result they always have to be shipped together.

Comment: @MarekR 1. code generator generates code 2. generated code uses external library 3. external library references symbols that are defined by the generated code. This is a framework or a middleware, and in any case an architecture I cannot change, since it is definded by my middleware. The issue disappears without the static library in the middle (as simulated by using OBJECT library), so I guess I am having these problems because I seperate MORE not less (main code from generated middleware code).

Comment: @KamilCuk So that I get the linker to link them twice. I need it to link ` -llibA.a -llibB.a -llibA.a -llibB.a` so that the cycle is resolved. For libraries that are created during the build, defining both dependencies would be the right way according to cmake documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html#id7 Not sure how it needs to look like in my case.

Comment: @kutschkem edit your question and add detailed information about generated code. How it is generated why it references library which uses generated code. Most probably you provided some template to the generator and this must be source of problems. I'm sure you can split not generated library to part which is used by generated code and link it to both libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too but was able to resolve the circular dependencies by first going to the CMakeLists.txt file for library "B":

```
add_library( libraryB STATIC ${libraryB_sources} )
set_target_properties( libraryB PROPERTIES PREFIX lib )
target_link_libraries( libraryB libraryA )
```

Then, in CMakeLists.txt for library A and the executable that links them both:

```
add_library( libraryA STATIC ${libraryA_sources} )
target_link_libraries( libraryA libraryB )

add_executable( myexe ${myexe_sources} )
target_link_libraries( myexe libraryA )
```

Comment: I think the key problem I had was that one of the libraries was an external target, a pre-compiled static library. What I wasn't able to do at the time was define a linking dependency between the pre-compiled lib and the one built with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Don't know how far back the features used here go
# so just adjust the range of CMake versions you can use
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23...3.26) 

project(StackOverflowProject)

# Define libA as an imported library
add_library(A STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(framework::A ALIAS A)
set_property(TARGET A PROPERTY
        # Set the location property of the imported library
        IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/to/my/framework/supplied/libA.a
)
# Link the framework library to your (soon to be)
# generated library libB.a
target_link_libraries(A INTERFACE generated::B)


# Define the generated code library
add_library(B STATIC)
add_library(generated::B ALIAS B)
# target_sources my be defined in one or more CMakeLists.txt files
target_sources(B PRIVATE b_generated_code.cpp)
# And link it to the supplied framework libA.a
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC framework::A)
# In case there is a deeper cyclic dependency between the
# libraries you can increase the default value of 2 repetitions
# with e.g.
set_property(TARGET B PROPERTY LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY 3)

# Your executable just links to the generated code and CMake will
# list "libB.a libA.a libB.a libA.a" when linking (or three times
# with LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY set to 3)
add_executable(execAB main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(execAB PRIVATE generated::B)
```

Comment: Huh, so basically it should work more or less out of the box now?

Comment: Yes, but it gets a little bit more difficult when the libraries are declared in different CMakeLists.txt files. You might want to move all the depdent library names `add_library(NAME STATIC ...)` to some central spot, then do the rest like adding source code and linkage in there respective CMakeLists.txt files.